# Append Interface Element Into Interface Golang

Tags: go

I have a function which accept all type of struct as interface. If I try to print

> s.Index(i)

It gives me the values. However once I append it into

> allRows []interface{}

and print it out. Instead of value I am getting the type of struct that I passed the function.
As an exapmle.

> fmt.Println("AllRows",allRows)
>
> [<adminPanel.allBeaconInfo Value> <adminPanel.allBeaconInfo Value>
> <adminPanel.allBeaconInfo Value> <adminPanel.allBeaconInfo Value>
> <adminPanel.allBeaconInfo Value>]

```
func pagination(c *gin.Context, st interface{})  {
            var allRows []interface{}
            switch reflect.TypeOf(st).Kind() {
            case reflect.Slice:
                s := reflect.ValueOf(st)
                for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
                    allRows=append(allRows,s.Index(i))
                    fmt.Println(allRows)
                }
            }
        
            fmt.Println("AllRows",allRows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `s.Index(i)` evaluates to a `reflect.Value` containing the actual slice element.  Call [Value.Interface()](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Interface) to get the actual slice element.

```
        var allRows []interface{}
        switch reflect.TypeOf(st).Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice:
            s := reflect.ValueOf(st)
            for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
                allRows=append(allRows,s.Index(i).Interface())
                fmt.Println(allRows)
            }
        }
```